# How to convert a number into a linked list of its digits in python

Tags: python

I was asked to convert a number into a linked list of its digits:
ex:`head = number_to_list(120)` number_to_list is the function I should write and it should return a list of its  digits `listutils.from_linked_list(head) == [1,2,0]` without using  datastructures like list and dicts.I tried to write inthis way:

```
def number_to_list(number):        
    head,tail = None,None
    for x in number:
        node = Node(x)
        if head:
           tail.next = node
        else:
           head = node
           tail = node
    second = head.next
    third = second.next
    fourth = third.next
```

But I know that I'm totally wrong because in the for loop I should write the code in such a way that it goes to the first digit of the number and create a node of it.I'm blocked here.Please help me with this.

Comment: How can you create a list without using a list?  Do you have a different list data structure you're using?

Comment: What are you trying to do with second=head.next etc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with by converting the number to a string and using list comprehension.

```
In [1]: foo = 12345

In [2]: [int(digit) for digit in str(foo)]
Out[2]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Or a shorter version suggested:

```
map(int, list(str(foo)))
```

But it seems like you're using a custom list class.  The key is still to convert the number to a string.

```
def number_to_list(number):        
    head = tail = None        #you can chain assignments if they have the same value
    for x in str(number):
        if not x.isdigit():
            continue # skip leading `-`
        node = Node(x)
        if head is not None:  #more pythonic than `if head`
           tail.next = node
        else:
           head = node
           tail = node
    return head    # don't forget your return code
```

Comment: `list(str(foo))` is shorter.

Comment: `listutils.from_linked_list(head) == [1,2,0]` not `listutils.from_linked_list(head) == ['1','2','0']`
So, `[int(digit) for digit in str(foo)]` instead of `[digit for digit in str(foo)]`

Comment: I have a method in listutils in converting the output to list.Now my problem is that for the code I have written to create a linked list it is not working...:(It was just returning an empty list...!!I think I should correct the code.

Comment: @Ramya Your original code doesn't return anything.  You need to conclude it with `return head`

Comment: @usmcs It worked fine thanyou .But ,if I give head = number_to_list(0) it was showing an error None type object has no attribute None.

Comment: It was perfect when I removed second.next and the other statements@usmcs

Comment: @Ramya  The version you posted assumed there would always be four digits.  You should have a much more general solution now.

Comment: yes you are right,and the new problem now is it is not working for negative numbers i.e;head = number_to_list(-120),How can I make it work for the negative numbers.@usmcs

Comment: What is the expected output?  Should it be [1,2,0] or [-1,2,0]?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46635/discussion-between-ramya-and-usmcs)

Comment: The output of `[int(digit) for digit in str(foo)]` is `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, not `['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']`.

Comment: don't we need to add tail = tail.next after tail.next = node to work?

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the number to a string and iterate through each character, converting them back to numbers when needed.

ex:

```
def number_to_list(number):        
    head,tail = None,None
    for x in str(number):
        #do stuff
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> def foobar(a):
>>>     if len(a) > 1:
>>>        return a[0]+','+foobar(a[1:])
>>>     else:
>>>        return a[0]
>>> 
>>> map(int,foobar(str(120)).split(','))
>>> [1, 2, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem will be solved if the code like this:

```
def number_to_list(number):        
    head,tail = None,None

    for x in str(number):
        node = Node(int(x))
        if head:
           tail.next = node
        else:
           head = node
           tail = node
    second = head.next
    third = second.next
    fourth = third.next
```